# How to know primary CPC in a Lens.org patent export?

Tags: patent-search, research, lens

I use Lens.org for all my patent reading and sometimes research. I was trying to export a collection and while Lens provides all the important data, I am facing some issues with the CPC column.

I am not sure which of the CPC is primary CPC for a patent in the export. All CPCs are kept in a single cell. How to know which one is primary without checking manually for each patent?

Edit: Usually the first CPC in a cell is primary on other database, but that wasn't the case in Lens export file as I checked.

[image: Attaching a screenshot from my recent export for reference]